# rails capistano mac os deploy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, git, ssh

When I used linux everything deploy work, but when I deploy from mac os, I have:

```
> cap production deploy
DEBUG [1330f96c] Running /usr/bin/env [ -d ~/.rvm ] on IP Adress
DEBUG [1330f96c] Command: [ -d ~/.rvm ]
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
user_name@ip_adress's password:
```

When I wrote password, I get

```
> DEBUG [de2b7c18] Finished in 4.376 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [1ca89b99] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm version on ip address
DEBUG [1ca89b99] Command: ~/.rvm/bin/rvm version
DEBUG [1ca89b99]    rvm 1.26.10 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
DEBUG [1ca89b99]    
DEBUG [1ca89b99] Finished in 1.130 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
rvm 1.26.10 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
DEBUG [1c973067] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm current on ip address
DEBUG [1c973067] Command: ~/.rvm/bin/rvm current
DEBUG [1c973067]    ruby-2.2.0
DEBUG [1c973067]    
DEBUG [1c973067] Finished in 2.110 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
ruby-2.2.0
DEBUG [848d3c3e] Running ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do ruby --version on ip address
DEBUG [848d3c3e] Command: ~/.rvm/bin/rvm default do ruby --version
DEBUG [848d3c3e]    ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
DEBUG [848d3c3e]    
DEBUG [848d3c3e] Finished in 1.050 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
INFO [8dbfa807] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/project/ on ip address
DEBUG [8dbfa807] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/project/
INFO [8dbfa807] Finished in 0.381 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/project/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
INFO Uploading /tmp/project/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO [0f9c9d2a] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/project/git-ssh.sh on ip address
DEBUG [0f9c9d2a] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/project/git-ssh.sh
INFO [0f9c9d2a] Finished in 1.417 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [5dfc2373] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:nick_name/project.git on ip address
DEBUG [5dfc2373] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/project/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:nick_name/project.git )
DEBUG [5dfc2373]    Enter passphrase for key '/home/nick_name/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

I install gem HighLine.

Please help me with this problem?

Comment: Its asking you for the passphrase for nick_name 's public key. Git uses this to identify when connecting to `bitbucket.org`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a key with no password, or make sure that if your user password and the key's passphrase are different that you are using the correct one.  The first prompt is for your user account, user_name@ip_adress, and the second is for the passphrase assigned to /home/nick_name/.ssh/id_rsa.

Comment: I change passphase for id_rsa in vps. And write this key after DEBUG [5dfc2373]    Enter passphrase for key '/home/nick_name/.ssh/id_rsa':, but nothing happens (